# Conversion of number/string into hexadecimal in C programming

Tags: c

How to convert number/string into hexadecimal? For instance,

Input a word: My name is Laura
Hexadecimal output:...

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  How is these data currently stored in your program?  Are they `int`s or `char` arrays?

Comment: You mean like `int a[] = { 84, 104, 105, 115 };`? Then `int n = sizeof a / sizeof *a; for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf (" 0x%02x", a[i]); putchar ('\n');`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: Does this relate to the CS50 course?

Comment: What I mean was how can you convert a user input to hexadecimal?

Comment: Enter a word: My name is Lulu.   Hexadecimal output:

Comment: The example I gave above was a mistake. My bad

Comment: @lululalali: Do you want the [ASCII Code values](http://www.asciitable.com/) of the user input to be printed out?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to convert a user's input to hexadecimal

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes

Comment: For example, how can I change "This is a cat" to hexadecimal?

Comment: @JohnKetterer It does not relate to CS50

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you have a word already stored in a `char` array, you could do

```
#include <string.h>

void print_in_hex(const char *string) {
    size_t len;

    len=strlen(string);
    for (size_t k=0; k<len; k++) {
        printf("%02x ", string[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```